# Update child class variables from base class

Tags: python, class-variables

I would like to know if there exists a way to update class variables in children from the base/parent. Is there a way for the birthday function to update the appropriate class variable?

I know that perhaps the proper way to do it in this example is to make age an instance variable. But I have a case where I would like to insist on making age a class variable.

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def birthday(self):
        self.age = self.age + 1


class Cat(Animal):
    age = 4


class Dog(Animal):
    age = 2


d = Dog()
print(Dog.age)
d.birthday()
print(Dog.age)
```

Comment: Why do you want `age` to be a class variable, rather than an instance variable?

Comment: If you *do* want a shared class attribute, then `birthday` should be a *class* method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value on the class.

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def birthday(self):
        self.__class__.age = self.__class__.age + 1
        # shorter version:
        # self.__class__.age += 1
```

Comment: Why access it via `self.__class__.__age__` when you could just make `birthday` a `classmethod`?

Comment: I would prefer `type(self).age` anyway; you typically do not want to work with dunder attributes directly.

Comment: I can't upvote. I accept this answer because it is the only answer and it gives a solution. However, I went on to actually use a class method.